# How to change an image from Cartesian to Polar coordinates in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, polar-coordinates

I am trying to convert the pixels of an image from x-y coordinate to polar coordinate and I have problem with it, as I want to code the function by myself. 
Here is the code I did so far:

```
function [ newImage ] = PolarCartRot
% read and show the image
image= imread('1.jpg');
%%imshow(image);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%change to polar coordinate
[x y z]= size(image);
r = sqrt(x*x+y*y);
theta = atan2(y,x);
for i =0:r
    for j= 0:theta
newpixel = [i; j];
newImage(newpixel(1), newpixel(2),:) = image(i,j,:);
    end
end
figure;
imshow (newImage);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. Can you add a clearer text description of what you want. For example: "for each pixel (i,j) in the new image, then I want to ..."

Comment: what i want is to write the function cart2pol with my own code like the answer below no using the one in matlab

Answer (score 16):

It is not quite clear what you are trying to do, which is why I am making my own example...

So given an image, I am converting the pixel x/y coordinates from Cartesian to polar with [CART2POL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cart2pol.html).

In the first figure, I am showing the locations of the points, and in the second, I plot both the original image and the one with polar coordinates.

Note that I am using the [WARP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/warp.html) function from the Image Processing Toolbox. Under the hood, it uses the [SURF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)/[SURFACE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface.html) function to display a texture-mapped image.

```
% load image 
load clown;
img = ind2rgb(X,map);
%img = imread(...);   % or use any other image

% convert pixel coordinates from cartesian to polar
[h,w,~] = size(img);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:w,1:h);
[theta,rho] = cart2pol(X, Y);
Z = zeros(size(theta));

% show pixel locations (subsample to get less dense points)
XX = X(1:8:end,1:4:end);
YY = Y(1:8:end,1:4:end);
tt = theta(1:8:end,1:4:end);
rr = rho(1:8:end,1:4:end);
subplot(121), scatter(XX(:),YY(:),3,'filled'), axis ij image
subplot(122), scatter(tt(:),rr(:),3,'filled'), axis ij square tight

% show images
figure
subplot(121), imshow(img), axis on
subplot(122), warp(theta, rho, Z, img), view(2), axis square
```

[image: pixel_coords]
[image: image_warped]

---

## EDIT

As I originally stated, the question is not clear. You have to describe the mapping you want in a well defined manner...

For one you need to think about where the origin is located before converting to polar coordinates. The previous example assume the origin to be the axes base at `(0,0)`. Suppose you want to take the center of the image `(w/2,h/2)` as origin, then you would do this instead:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid((1:w)-floor(w/2), (1:h)-floor(h/2));
```

with the rest of the code unchanged. To better illustrate the effect, consider a source image with [concentric circles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34695166/97160) drawn in Cartesian coordinates, and notice how they map to straight lines in polar coordinates when using the center of the circles as origin:

[image: concentric_circles]

---

## EDIT

Here is another example of how to display an image in polar coordinates as requested in the comments. Note that we perform the mapping in the inverse direction `pol2cart`:

```
[h,w,~] = size(img);
s = min(h,w)/2;
[rho,theta] = meshgrid(linspace(0,s-1,s), linspace(0,2*pi));
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta, rho);
z = zeros(size(x));
subplot(121), imshow(img)
subplot(122), warp(x, y, z, img), view(2), axis square tight off
```

[image: image_polar]

Again the effect is better show if you feed it an input image with straight lines, and see how they map in polar coordinates (vertical lines become circles, and horizontal lines become rays emanating from the origin):

[image: straight_lines]

Comment: i need to convert it without using cart2pol

Comment: @hinatachan: its a very simply function: Replace `[theta rho] = cart2pol(X, Y);` with `theta = atan2(Y,X);` and `rho = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);` just like you already did in your question (though we are working with matrices not scalars)

Comment: @Masi: did you even try it? The example is complete as is... Both `X` and `map` come from `clown.mat` which ships with MATLAB; it loads an indexed image and its corresponding color map. As for the 360-rotation-mapped-image, I added another example, see the edit..

Comment: @Masi: this is really basic image handling in MATLAB... I updated the example so you can use any image you want. You can read more about the different image types here (indexed, grayscale, truecolor): https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html

Comment: @Amro Can you please add the source of the colourful concentric picture source in the code example. I really want test your new proposals. - - You also change the symbols from capital `X,Y` to small `x,y` in last example. Is there any reason for that? - - Can you please explain why you take `s` as average of height and width (`=min(h,w)/2`) in the last example. I think you take the center of the image there.

Comment: @Masi here are the pattern images if you want to try it yourself: [circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcMGo.png), [vlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdE20.png), [hlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLLqn.png). Note that the last example is a separate one; the mapping is done in the inverse direction, where we start with `rho`/`theta` and get `X`/`Y`. The variable `s` here controls the max radius in `rho`, it's not the center, you can really use any other value, but the size of the matrix produced by `meshgrid` will depend on it. Also you don't necessarily have to start at 0 in that `linspace`.

Comment: @Amro I extended the polar axes and polar grid case in the thread here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40030096/54964

Comment: @Amro do you know how to do this *`warp`* in python. I need to achieve the plot where the origin is at the middle.

Comment: @Minato See this for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17142979/97160 (note that the [`warp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/warp.html) function creates a texture-mapped surface like in that example). Also you could use packages like [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) and [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) which have spatial transformations and remapping functions..

Comment: @Amro thanks for the heads up though I did solve my problem by doing some tweaking around some stuff. I now need to reproject the warped image into the original one after applying some filters to the warped version.

Comment: @Minato sounds like you should create a new and separate Python question. Feel free to link to this one :)