# equivalent from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, plot, 3d, texture-mapping

I just have started with Python and I would translate this example from MATLAB to Python, but I have not found the equivalent in Python.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface.html

```matlab
load clown
surface(peaks,flipud(X),...
    'FaceColor','texturemap',...
    'EdgeColor','none',...
    'CDataMapping','direct')
colormap(map)
view(-35,45)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked around for packages that can do... whatever `surface()` does?

Comment: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html

Comment: maybe you can skip `load clown`...

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? - http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.surf  Wasn't sure, so, didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: I want to put the image "clown" about a general surface as in this example

Comment: Matplotlib has a 3d surface plot - http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib offers nearly all plotting options Matlab does. Surface plots can be done as well: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots

To load images scipy has a PIL-wrapper (no clown included, sorry), which loads matplotlib-compatible numpy arrays.

To sum up, you want the following packages: numpy, scipy, matplotlib and PIL. The combination of those four libraries should give you all you need. Also check out the pylab interface of these libraries, as it is very similar to Matlab.

Example that does what I believe you want to do:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.misc import imread
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
from numpy import linspace, meshgrid, sqrt, sin, mean, flipud

clown = imread('clown.png')
fig = figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = linspace(-5, 5, clown.shape[0])
Y = linspace(-5, 5, clown.shape[1])
X, Y = meshgrid(X, Y)
R = sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = sin(R)
clown = clown.swapaxes(0,1) / 255. # meshgrid orients axes the other way around, scaling of rgb to [0-1]
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=flipud(clown))
ax.view_init(45,-35) # swapped wrt matlab
show()
```