# How to pass surface map output of Matlab warp to export_fig?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Warp object is in polar coordinates which I cannot assign with `axes` so I cannot pass the surface object directly to `export_fig`. 
**Code which generates the image** but I cannot catch it for `export_fig` as shown below because no handle for it

```
clear all; close all; clc; 
img=imread('peppers.png'); 
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/7586650/54964
[h,w,~] = size(img);
s = min(h,w)/2;
[rho,theta] = meshgrid(linspace(0,s-1,s), linspace(0,2*pi,s));
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta, rho);
z = zeros(size(x));
figure;
h=warp(x, y, z, img); 
view(2), axis square tight off
```

The `export_fig` accepts the figure and syntax handlers but not the surface map so I cannot pass `h` to the function

```
% https://github.com/altmany/export_fig
export_fig(figure_handle, filename);
export_fig(axes_handle, filename);
```

### Example code which fails with proposals

```
clear all; close all; clc; 

fp=figure();
hax_polar=axes(fp);

f_do_not_touch=figure('Name', 'Do not touch'); 

index=0;
I=imread('peppers.png'); 
while index < 7
    [x, y, z]=makePolar(I);
    h=warp(x, y, z, I);
    view(2), axis square tight off
    %
    [Ip, alpha] = export_fig('/home/masi/Images/masi', '-png', '-native', '-q101', '-a1', '-m1', '-RGB', '-nofontswap',  '-transparent', '-dpng', ...
        hax_polar);
    p=FastPeakFind(Ip); % https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder
    imagesc(hax_polar, Ip); hold on
    plot(hax_polar, p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'r+')
    hold off
    index=index+1;
end

function [x, y, z]=makePolar(img)
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/7586650/54964
[h,w,~] = size(img);
s = min(h,w)/2;
[rho,theta] = meshgrid(linspace(0,s-1,s), linspace(0,2*pi,s));
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta, rho);
z = zeros(size(x));
end
```

Fig. 1 Output where the figure `Do not touch` gets content and the main figure breaks because implicit declarations

[image]

Matlab: 2016a
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit

Comment: plase, do consider adding a [mcve]. This means that a direct copy paste will run the code. This is important because you are doing very specific stuff and we can not just guess, we migth miss your error.

Comment: Also, what does `export_fig` has to do with anything? the warning appears in `surface`

Comment: the image generations is great. `figure_handle` and `filename` do not exist in your code, so it errors. Thats what I meant.

Comment: if I take the first peice of code in this question, and then do `export_fig(gcf,'masi.png')` I can suseccfully save the image

Comment: Doest it matter? if I do `figure_handle=figure; h=warp(x, y, z, img); 
view(2), axis square tight off;

filename='whatevers.png'
export_fig(figure_handle, filename);` it also works

Comment: *Can you pass figure_handle explicitly to warp* : WHAT? I havent done that and neither that is in your question. What?

Comment: Use `h_ax = get(h, 'Parent')` to get the handle of the axes containing the surface, then pass `h_ax` to export_fig.

Comment: There is nothing implicit. `figure_handle=figure;` is very very explicit

Comment: @AnderBiguri Please, see the body. Now, you will see that it will fail when you have to deal with many figures.

Comment: I will have a look at this tomorrow. Meanwhile consider looking at your previous questions and accepting the ones that solved you problems (not only mine, if it did, but thre are more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues that if we fix them we get what you expect.

1. Since `warp` doesn't accept a `'Parent'` property, you need to be sure that the `axes` on which you want it to appear is the current axes. You can force this by using the `axes` function and pass the axes handle to it.

   ```
   axes(hax_polar)
   h = warp(x, y, z, I);

   % Explicitly modify this axes
   view(hax_polar, 2)
   axis(hax_polar, 'square')
   axis(hax_polar, 'tight')
   axis(hax_polar, 'off')
   ```
2. When calling `imagesc` and `plot` it is much clearer (and works more reliably across systems) to use the `'Parent'` property value pair rather than specifying the parent as the first input.

   ```
   imagesc(Ip, 'Parent', hax_polar);
   plot(p(1:2:end), p(2:2:end), 'r+', 'Parent', hax_polar);
   hold(hax_polar, 'off')
   ```

Once we fix all of these things, we get an image that looks like what appears to be correct

[image]

```
clear all; close all; clc;

fp=figure();
hax_polar=axes('Parent', fp);

f_do_not_touch=figure('Name', 'Do not touch');

index=0;
I=imread('peppers.png');
while index < 7
    [x, y, z]=makePolar(I);

    axes(hax_polar)

    h=warp(x, y, z, I);

    % Different
    view(hax_polar, 2);
    axis(hax_polar, 'square')
    axis(hax_polar, 'tight')
    axis(hax_polar, 'off')
    %
    [Ip, alpha] = export_fig('test.png', '-png', '-native', '-q101', '-a1', '-m1', '-RGB', '-nofontswap',  '-transparent', '-dpng', ...
        hax_polar);
    p=FastPeakFind(Ip); % https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37388-fast-2d-peak-finder
    imagesc(Ip, 'Parent', hax_polar); hold on
    plot(p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'r+', 'Parent', hax_polar)
    hold(hax_polar, 'off')
    index=index+1;
end

function [x, y, z]=makePolar(img)
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/7586650/54964
[h,w,~] = size(img);
s = min(h,w)/2;
[rho,theta] = meshgrid(linspace(0,s-1,s), linspace(0,2*pi,s));
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta, rho);
z = zeros(size(x));
```

Comment: @Masi I'm not sure what you mean by "assert statements". But if you want your code to work on all versions, it's important to do that *and* it's nice and explicit and easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: @Masi No. Just read the documentation on when you can/can't use it.

Comment: @Masi So it looks like on newer versions you *don't* need the `'Parent'` property value so I've modified my answer slightly. The new first point is really the cause of your issue though