# How to use polar axes with Matlab warp?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, polar-coordinates

I want to use `polaraxes` on the `warp` object on the half circumference of the polar presentation. Code without `polaraxes` but with `warp`

```
close all; clear all; clc; 

% https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586650/54964
load clown;
img = ind2rgb(X,map);
[h,w,~] = size(img);
s = min(h,w)/2;
[rho,theta] = meshgrid(linspace(0,s-1,s), linspace(0,pi));
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta, rho);
z = zeros(size(x));

f1=figure();  
hax=axes('Parent', f1); 
imagesc(img, 'Parent', hax);
box(hax, 'off');
axis(hax, 'off');
set(hax, 'yTickLabel', []);
set(hax, 'xTickLabel', []); % for polar presentation
set(hax, 'Ticklength', [0 0]); % https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529630/54964

f2=figure();
hax2=axes('Parent', f2); 
h=warp(x, y, z, img); 
view(hax2, 2); 
axis(hax2, 'square'); 
axis(hax2, 'tight');
```

Fig.1 Current output Cartesian clown, 
Fig. 2 Polar clown on half circumference but without polaraxes, 
Fig. 3 Output of Section 2 after troubleshoots (EBH, masi)

[image]
[image]

Pseudocode unsuccessfully with `polaraxes` and `warp`; I can only do `polaraxes` with `polarplot` which is not enough here

```
hax2=polaraxes('Parent', f2); 
h=warp(x,y,z, img);
```

Expected output: polaraxes on the half circumference

### 2 Testing EBH's proposals

1. pax=polaraxes, 2. loop, 3. warp(I) into pax - looping added
2. Implicit commands view and axis fail - test code added `af = figure('Name', 'Do Not Touch');` to show why the implicit commands fail
3. Test code with `FastPeakFind` and more test images, Image drawing and Image orientation fixes

Summary

```
close all; clear all; clc;

fp=figure('Name', 'Test', ...
    'Position',[200 200 851 404],'Resize','off'); % only half circle in polaraxes although warp can do eclipses
ThetaTicks = 0*pi:pi/10:1*pi;
pax = polaraxes( 'ThetaAxisUnits', 'radians', ...
    'ThetaLim',[min(ThetaTicks) max(ThetaTicks)],...
    'Color','none',...
    'GridAlpha',1,...
    'GridColor',[1 1 1],...
    'ThetaTick',ThetaTicks, ...
    'Parent', fp);

af = figure('Name', 'Do Not Touch');

testImages = { 'peppers.png', 'bag.png', 'glass.png', 'circles.png', 'fabric.png', 'testpat1.png', 'office_1.jpg', ...
'onion.png', 'pears.png', 'rice.png', 'westconcordorthophoto.png', 'coins.png' };
imax = axes('Parent', fp, 'Visible', 'off');
for testImage=testImages
    I = imread(testImage{1,1});
    angleRadians=-pi;
    [x, y, z]=makePolar(I, angleRadians);
    fp=figure(fp); % put this every time you switch between figures to go back to 'fp'
    imax.Children = warp(x, y, z, I); 
    set(imax,'view',[-180 -90],'Visible','off')
    axis(imax,'tight'); 
    pause(1);

    % https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006051/54964
    Ip=getframe(pax);
    Ip=Ip.cdata;
    imwrite(Ip, '/tmp/testMasi.png', 'png');
    assert(isa(Ip, 'uint8'), sprintf('I is not uint8 but %s', class(Ip)));
    p=FastPeakFind(Ip);
    imagesc(Ip, 'Parent', imax);
    axis(imax, 'off');
    hold(imax, 'on');
    plot(p(1:2:end),p(2:2:end),'r+', 'Parent', imax);
    hold(imax, 'off');
    drawnow; 
end
```

Output in Fig. 3 where buggy radar axis; trying to troubleshoot it in the thread [How to integrate Java swing black background toolbar into polaraxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40086038/54964)

Matlab: 2016b
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is plotting the warpped image on a polar axes, using different axes for each:

```
% first we create a figure with defined size, because 'polaraxes' are always
% half a circle, and we need to keep the output surface of 'warp' in this
% shape, and not in an ellipse. Switching off the 'Resize' is just an option
fp = figure('Name', 'Test', ...
    'Position',[200 200 851 404],'Resize','off'); 
% Then we define the polaraxes:
ThetaTicks = 0:pi/10:pi; % for the opposite side use pi:pi/10:2*pi
pax = polaraxes( 'ThetaAxisUnits', 'radians', ...
    'ThetaLim',[min(ThetaTicks) max(ThetaTicks)],...
    'ThetaTick',ThetaTicks, ...
    'Parent', fp);

testImages = {'peppers.png', 'bag.png', 'glass.png', 'circles.png',...
    'fabric.png', 'testpat1.png', 'office_1.jpg', 'pears.png',...
    'rice.png', 'westconcordorthophoto.png', 'coins.png'};

figure(fp) %<-- put this every time you want to bring the focuse back to 'fp'
imax = axes('Parent',fp); % this will be the axes for the image
for testImage = testImages
    I = imread(testImage{1,1});
    angleRadians = -pi; % for the opposite side use pi
    [h,w,~] = size(I);
    s = min(h,w)/2;
    [rho,theta] = meshgrid(linspace(0,s-1,s), linspace(0,angleRadians,s));
    [x,y] = pol2cart(theta, rho);
    z = zeros(size(x));
    imax.Children = warp(x, y, z, I); % display the image in 3D surface
    set(imax,'view',[0 90],'Visible','off'); % rotate to a top view and hide the axes
    axis(imax,'tight') % calibrate the image to the figure size
    drawnow;
    pause(0.5)
end
```

[image: polar image]

The main cavet is `polaraxes` creates half circle, while the `warp` creates half ellipse that depends on the size of the figure, so you have to set correctly the figure size.

Comment: @Masi Not that I'm aware of. Using `polaraxes` always creates half a circle, and keeps it in the same ratio while resizing the figure.

Comment: @Masi I don't know which window you want to make transparent. Right now the polar axes are transparent. For the rest of your comment see my edit.

Comment: @Masi I have edited the last part of the code to deal with this issue.

Comment: Have A look on ['ThetaDir'](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polaraxes-properties.html#property_ThetaDir)

Comment: @Masi try setting the view to [-180 -90] (`set(imax,'view',[-180 -90],'Visible','off');`). Is this the type of rotation you look for?

Comment: @Masi `angleRadians = -pi;` (instead of pi).

Comment: @Masi and please, edit your question to be more general and readable, right now it's a collection of code blocks with no clear goal (the result of keep asking for semi-related issues in the comments). Once you do this, I can edit my answer to suite the question, and som explanations to it.

Comment: I have also made my answer more compact.

Comment: Good! Only the difference is that I have onion at the right-side, while you have at the left side.  - - For some reason, the `makePolar` flips vertically when working with half-circles.  I think nothing wrong with the function but the specific application requires the flipping vertically i.e. onion to the right.