# How to integrate Java swing black background toolbar into polaraxes?

Tags: java, matlab, swing, matlab-figure, polar-coordinates

Code where I try to integrate shortened version of Altman's MATLAB 2013 polar radar system [code](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-figure-toolbar-background) into MATLAB 2016b polarxes implementation because I want to have black background in toolbar and zoom feature with horiozontal scrollbar. 
The former code basically uses `javax.swing.JSlider` having a `continuous-movement callback`. 
The current bug comes from the line `'StateChangedCallback',{@cbSlider,fp,imax});` where axes `imax` does not behave as expected

```
close all; clear all; clc;    
% http://stackoverflow.com/q/40030096/54964
fp=figure('Name', 'Test', ...
    'Position',[200 200 851 404],'Resize','off'); % only half circle in polaraxes although warp can do eclipses
ThetaTicks = 0*pi:pi/10:1*pi;
pax = polaraxes( 'ThetaAxisUnits', 'radians', ...
    'ThetaLim',[min(ThetaTicks) max(ThetaTicks)],...
    'Color','none',...
    'GridAlpha',1,...
    'GridColor',[1 1 1],...
    'ThetaTick', ThetaTicks, ...
    'ThetaDir', 'counterclockwise', ...
    'Parent', fp);

af = figure('Name', 'Do Not Touch');

testImage = 'peppers.png';
imax = axes('Parent', fp, 'Visible', 'off');
I = imread(testImage);
angleRadians=-pi;
[x, y, z]=makePolar(I, angleRadians);
fp=figure(fp); 
imax.Children = warp(x, y, z, I);
set(imax,'view',[-180 -90],'Visible','off');
axis(imax,'tight')
pause(1);

%% Change toolbar bakcgrounds black like radar systems
% http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-figure-toolbar-background
[jSlider,hSlider] = javacomponent('javax.swing.JSlider',[0,0,.01,0.1],fp);
set(hSlider, 'Units','norm','pos',[.15,0,.7,.05]);
set(jSlider, 'Background',java.awt.Color.black, ...
    'Value',0, 'Maximum',duration, ...
    'StateChangedCallback',{@cbSlider,fp,imax});

hToolbar = findall(fp,'tag','FigureToolBar');

% required to programmatically alter the figure
delete(findall(hToolbar,'tag','Plottools.PlottoolsOn'))
delete(findall(hToolbar,'tag','Plottools.PlottoolsOff'))
delete(findall(hToolbar,'tag','Annotation.InsertColorbar'))
delete(findall(hToolbar,'tag','DataManager.Linking'))
delete(findall(hToolbar,'tag','Standard.EditPlot'))

% ensure the toolbar is visible onscreen
drawnow;

% Get the underlying JToolBar component
jToolbar = get(get(hToolbar,'JavaContainer'),'ComponentPeer');

% Set the bgcolor to black
color = java.awt.Color.black;
jToolbar.setBackground(color);
jToolbar.getParent.getParent.setBackground(color);
```

Output where I am not sure which array it is about

```
Error using javahandle_withcallbacks.javax.swing.JSlider/set
Array must be numeric or logical.

Error in test_polar_radar_system (line 33)
set(jSlider, 'Background',java.awt.Color.black, ...
```

Fig. 1 Current output where the horizontal scrolling bar works but has no successful bind to action, 
Fig. 2 Expected output = half circle of Altman's output but with the test image and axis starting point like in Fig. 1 but everything else can be like Altman's

[image]
[image]

### Attempt 2 unsuccessfully

```
% https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164766
color = java.awt.Color.blue;
color = java.awt.Color(0,0,0.9); % alternative declaration
hToolbar=findall(gcf,'tag','FigureToolBar');
jToolbar=get(get(hToolbar,'JavaContainer'),'ComponentPeer');
jToolbar.setBackground(color)
```

Output

```
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in make_sample (line 822)
                jToolbar.setBackground(color)
```

MATLAB: 2016b
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Linux kernel: 4.6 backports

Answer (score 2):

Your bug is probably not in setting the `StateChangedCallback` but in setting the `Maximum` i.e., instead of providing a simple number you probably have something else in your `duration` variable. Because of this the entire `set()` command fails and the `StateChangedCallback` is not assigned.

Comment: I have in duration variable `00:00:00`. What is the expected content?

Comment: a positive integer number