# visualizing coordinate systems in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to visualize 2D coordinate systems in Matlab, given the equations of the transformations.I want to generate images which look something like this:

[image: coordinate grid example]

If it is say a transformation from x & y to a & b can I set the grid points at regular intervals of a and b and have straight lines join them, thus illustrating the new coordinate systems?

P.S. : it is important to not have smooth curves, but straight lines joining discrete points.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. It is a site to help you fix specific solutions to problems that run into specific issues. Please make an attempt and we will help you fix what's broken. It seems like you have a good idea, but you need to work on it yourself first.

Comment: You may want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030096/how-to-use-polar-axes-with-matlab-warp)