# Image to Polar Transformation

Tags: matlab, transformation, polar-coordinates

I need to transform a black/white image to polar coordinates. The original image is saved in a matrix. Right now, I'm iterating through each pixel of the original image and I calculate the polar transformation of each pixel like this:

```
originX = 0;
originY = 0;



for x = 1:columns
    for y = 1:rows
        r = sqrt((x-originX)^2 + (y-originY)^2);
        a = atand((y-originY)/(x-originX));

        polarTrans(r, a) = origImage(x,y);
    end
end
```

The problem is, the calculated new positions for the pixels are NOT positive integer values, so I can't simply save them into another matrix *polarTrans*. Do you have any suggestions here? How else should I save the transformed image if not in a matrix?

Comment: What about a (x,y) matrix with values `polarTrans(x,y)=[r a origImag(X,Y)]`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the outcome? What will the matrix look like? I get "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." when I try it.

Comment: My fail, it was indeed `polarTrans(x,y,:)=[r a origImag(X,Y)]` that i meant, a 3D matrix. You can use also a cell if you prefer.

Comment: Oh I see it's a 3D matrix. So is there any way I can e.g. perform imshow(polarTrans) to plot the transformed matrix?

Comment: About plotting, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586650/2107764), maybe it will help you out. Notice that it uses a similar scheme as [Ander Biguri answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381770/2107764).

Comment: @Aydo  -- Please also have a look at [this contribution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16094-polar-coordinates-transform) on the website of Mathworks.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorize, my friend.

```
% compute all [x,y] pairs for the whole image 
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:columns -Xorigin,1:rows -Yorigin);

% Ta-da! 
[alpha,rho]=cart2pol(x,y)
```

Now pixel `[i,j]` is `[x(i,j), y(i,j)]` in cartesian coordinates and `[rho(i,j),alpha(i,j)]` in polar coordinates. You have no need of storing `originImage` in any other way. Whenever you want to know the polar coordinates of an specific pixel value, you just do `[rho(i,j),alpha(i,j)]`, for `originImage(i,j)` pixel value.

Comment: It's `[alpha,rho] = cart2pol(x,y)` instead, the order of angle is first and radius is second, also `cart2pol` not `car2pol`. (+1) though for *Vectorize, my friend*, actually, vectorization is the worst thing Matlab has taught us.

Comment: @AboAmmar opps I wrote it from memory, let me fix that. Why do you not like vectorization? It makes us lazy?

Comment: I like vectorization, it makes our life easy, but it is the total opposite of how the computer works under the hood, it consumes huge memory by keeping large matrices and vectors allocated, and sometimes hides the real algorithm. Almost all other languages discourage vectorization for performance reasons. I hoped a real parallel computer exists.

Comment: @AboAmmar fair, but ah, its so useful so often, specially for scipting (MATLAB!). Generally if you are worried about memory or low level computing, either you just do not use MATLAB, or learn how it works under the hood (last one is always encouraged anyway)